# How to change back color on focus tools by dynamically in c#.net desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, backcolor

In my desktop form there are many control. I want to change back color of that active control on Focus & back to its Original color once it lost focus.

Here is my code,

```
public BillingMetal(Billing _frm)
{
    this.frm = _frm;
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.GotFocus += ctrl_GotFocus;
        ctrl.LostFocus += ctrl_LostFocus;
    }
}

public void ctrl_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = sender as Control;
    if (ctrl.Tag is Color)
        ctrl.BackColor = (Color)ctrl.Tag;
}

public void ctrl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = sender as Control;
    ctrl.Tag = ctrl.BackColor;
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

**Actually this code is working but for the button only not for textbox, combobox or any other tools.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems basically ok but you would want to make sure that you iterated all the children (of all the children...) of your Control tree as well.

[image: combo, textbox etc in panel]

```
public partial class BillingMetal : Form
{
    public BillingMetal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (var ctrl in IterateControls(Controls))
        {
            ctrl.GotFocus += (sender, e) =>
            { 
                if(sender is Control ctrl)
                {
                    ctrl.Tag = ctrl.BackColor;
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            };
            ctrl.LostFocus += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if(sender is Control ctrl && ctrl.Tag is Color color)
                {
                    ctrl.BackColor = color;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

**Iterator**

```
    IEnumerable<Control> IterateControls(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control child in IterateControls(control.Controls))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```